# How to make an element retrieved by an API selected by default

Tags: angular

Its a simple issue, i guess, but i couldn't find a suitable answer in my search, here. I have this list of names coming from an API and a feature for the selected ones: name turns red (CSS), an image comes up and details about the person get into these input fields (also coming from API). But when I load the page, none is selected (of course) and the page gets user "unfrieldly". How can I have the first one selected by default? Here's how it looks like when selected (and how i want it to be by default):
[image]

And this is like I have it now:

[image]

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="people">
      <ul *ngFor="let star of people.results">
        <li (click)="onSelect(star)" [class.selected]="star === selectedPeople">{{star.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-7" *ngIf="picture">
      <img class="img-fluid" [src]="getImageUrl(selectedPeople)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="row">
        <label>Height</label>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedPeople">
        <div class="row">
          <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.height">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Hair</label>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedPeople">
        <div class="row">
          <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.hair_color">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Mass</label>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedPeople">
        <div class="row">
          <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.mass">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Eyes</label>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="selectedPeople">
        <div class="row">
          <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople.eye_color">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
people: People;
  selectedPeople: People;
  picture=false;
  loading = false;

  constructor(private starService: StarService) {
    this.getChars();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getImageUrl(person) {
    return "../../assets/" + person.name + ".jpg";
  }


  onSelect(persona: People): void {
    this.selectedPeople = persona;
    this.picture=true;
  }


  getChars() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.starService.getChars().subscribe(data => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.people = data;
      console.log(this.people)
    });
  }



}
```

This is the People Interface:

```
export interface People {
  birth_year: string;
  films:Films
  created: string;
  edited: string;
  eye_color: string;
  gender: string;
  hair_color: string;
  height: string;
  mass: string;
  name: string;
  skin_color: string;
  starships: Starships;
  url: string;
 }
```

Comment: Just call your `onSelect` within the subscribe method.

Comment: Also ... is `People` defined as an array? Or as a single person? It looks like it is an array as you are getting it back on a request for all of the characters. But then in the `onSelect` parameter, you are using it as the data type of the *one* person you are passing in?

Comment: with your solution the page doesnt load now, it gets stuck

Comment: Did you use the code Dharmaraj posted below? How does it get stuck?

Comment: console.log(this.people[0]) I get undefined here

Comment: Did you see my question? What is People? Is it a class? An interface? An array? It looks like in your code that you are using it *both* as an array of people (characters) and as a single person (character).

Comment: Ive edited, People is an Interface, you can see it now

Comment: can you log console.log(data); what type of data you are receiving from API

Comment: yes, Ill post the api answer

Comment: Doing a stackblitz example would be even more helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are some data typing issues here. How about something like this:

```
  people: People[];             // This should be an array of people
  selectedPeople: People;       // This is just one person
  picture=false;
  loading = false;

  constructor(private starService: StarService) {
    // this.getChars();        // This should be in the onInit

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChars();
  }

  getImageUrl(person) {
    return "../../assets/" + person.name + ".jpg";
  }


  onSelect(persona: People): void {
    this.selectedPeople = persona;
    this.picture=true;
  }


  getChars() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.starService.getChars().subscribe(data => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.people = data.results;  // Seems that this should be the results
      this.onSelect(this.people[0]); // Then you can treat people as a simple array.
      console.log(this.people)
    });
  }

}
```

The HTML also needs to change:

```
<ul *ngFor="let star of people">
```

This is now just `people` and not `people.results` because we already pulled the results off in the getChars method and set the `people` property to the actual list of people.

Comment: Ok, that worked, Luke is on the screen, but i lost the list...Why?

Comment: Your HTML also needs to change. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Mark my answer? I dont follow...Ive checked you answer as correct, and thanks again, i've learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 2):

You can call onSelect method in subscribe and pass the first element to onSelect function.

```
  getChars() {
this.loading = true;
this.starService.getChars().subscribe(data => {
  this.loading = false;
  this.people = data;
  this.onSelect( this.people.results[0]);
  console.log(this.people)
});
```

}

Hope this will work.

The better approch to load data using ngOnit() you can call this.getChars(); in ngOnInit rather than constructor.

Comment: I think that may still be incorrect? It should be `this.people.results[0]`?

Comment: yes as per above code it should be this.people.results[0]

Comment: i think data needs to be transformed to People using map operator.